# A cost minimization problem in energy allocation

Tags: python, machine-learning, optimization, linear-programming

I have a cost minimization problem in energy allocation. The problem may take a while to describe. Suppose we have a building that needs, say, 5000 units of energy per day during work hours, 4;00 to 13:00. We have a generator that can supply either 500 or 800 units of energy per hour, either directly to the building or to a battery which can supply energy later during work hours.The bettery has a capacity of, say, 4000. The rate at which the battery supplies energy can vary. Now I would like a scheduling of the working status of the generator (e.g. supplies energy directly to the building, to the battery or does not work) and the battery.

There are a few constraints to consider. The first one is that the electricity price varies. 0.2 dollars per hour for 23:00 to 7:00, 0.3 dollars per hour for 7:00 to 8:00 and 12:00 to 18:00, and 0.5 dollars per hour for 8:00 to 12:00 and 18:00 to 23:00. So we want the battery to store energy supplied by the generator during low price hours and supply energy to the building duiring high price hours. The second one is that we want the energy supplied to be steady.

My approach is to use linear programming. Assign a value x_1,j of 0 or 1 to indicate whether the generator supplies energy directly to the building during hour j. Assign a value x_2,j of 0 or 1 to indicate whether the generator supplies energy to the battery during hour j. Assign a value x_3,j of 0 or 1 to indicate whether the battery supplies energy to the building during hour j. So we have an LP with a minimization objective function. However, I am afraid that this may be computationally expensive and take a long time.

I was wondering if there were any better solutions. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you in advance. By the way I am using Python.

Comment: This seems to be more of a math problem than a programming one..

Comment: Maybe more suitable for https://or.stackexchange.com/

Comment: MIP models are not by definition computationally expensive. If models are not very large and we have access to a good MIP solver, we can get good solutions very quickly.